# Making TextView in center / bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is the code I use what should change in it?

```
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
android:gravity="center" 
android:autoLink="web"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:id="@id/txtDefaultpassword" 
android:padding="40.0px" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/defaultpassword" />
```

Comment: For gravity center and bottom You should use `center_horizontal | bottom`

Answer (score 1):

layout_width should be match_parent.

```
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:id="@id/txtDefaultpassword"
            android:padding="40.0px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/defaultpassword" />
```